# use whatsapp business app control bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-smart-home

use whatsapp in smart home.

I want develope a whatsapp business app to control bluetooth light or other smart devices

It can be run on the WhatsApp applet to obtain data from Bluetooth devices, control instructions for Bluetooth devices, and control Bluetooth devices in smart homes.

Please tell me, how to connect to a Bluetooth device in the WhatsApp applet? For example, how can a smart ring be paired with the ring and read the ring's health data?

Comment: Great Idea! Do you have any specific question? Please take the [tour] and and the [ask] page to improve your question

Comment: Please tell me, how to connect to a Bluetooth device in the WhatsApp applet? For example, how can a smart ring be paired with the ring and read the ring's health data?

Comment: I have no idea, but please [edit] your question to include every question there. Also it would be best to use better tags such as [whatsapp] or [whatsapp-cloud-api]